# Will the number of shards on sharded Ethereum change dynamically?

Tags: sharding

I am not familiar with how sharding would work in Ethereum. I am working on an indexer type of application for blockchains and I want to understand how the number of shards in Ethereum might change over time.

Would new shards get automatically introduced?

Comment: As far as I know, the Ethereum sharding roadmap is not finalised yet, so answer to this question is most likely "it depends"